# run command with root privileges as nonroot user

Tags: linux, sudo

I want to set up steam to run automatically with a higher than default priority, which involves starting it with nice. But to set a priority lower than 0, I must be root. Problem is that steam doesn't like to be started as root, so if I do something like sudo nice -n -1 steam it says that it cannot be started as root. Furthermore, if I use sudo -u myusername nice -n -1 steam, nice complains that it hasn't got the privileges to set that priority.

I used visudo to give myuser the privilege to run sudo nice without password, but it was futile.

I know this HAS to have been answered somewhere else, but I don't know how to search.. it's a rather specific problem.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: using renice AFTER I started steam won't do, because the child processes (games) won't inherit the nice value from the parent that way

Comment: Can;t you just start it as a user and then `renice` is as root ?

Comment: if I use renice then the children processes won't gain the same nice value :(

Answer (score 3):

People on the steam forum have suggested to start screen, renice that, and then run steam under its control.  Does that work for you?

Comment: I don't understand how this answers my question. I'm not having problems running steam, I want to give it a higher priority so that it uses more of my olddated hardware

Comment: Yes.  And if you adjust the niceness of the screen session the steam you execute from within it will inherit its niceness.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just need to rearrange the pieces you already have: become root, and type

> `nice -n -1 sudo -u`*yourusername*`steam`

<sub>[edit]</sub>
or

> `nice -n -1 su`*yourusername*`-c steam`

The idea being that you

1. Become privileged,
2. Set priority higher than the default (numerically lower than 0), which requires privileges,
3. Use `sudo` or `su` to revert to your normal (non-privileged) identity
   (but, hopefully, retain the priority you set in the previous step), and then
4. Run the (`steam`) command, with elevated priority but not elevated privileges.